# Options for following the Norway Chess tournament live

Tags: tournament, norway-chess

I've heard a new tournament format is being adopted in the new series of Norway Chess, where each drawn classical game is followed by an Armageddon game in order to conclude with a decisive result for each match-up.

What are the recommended (free) websites for following the event live other than the official coverage of the tournament?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the event live from various platforms, to name a few:

**Chess24**: live broadcast of moves and engine analysis available to all
users, and the live commentary provided by Jan Gustafsson and Peter
Svidler restricted to premium members for this event.
But all broadcasts are recorded and available freely on their youtube
channel, including Peter Svidler's analysis of a game of the round.

- [Chess24's page for current round](https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/altibox-norway-chess-2019/5/1/1)
- [Related uploaded videos on their youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/chess24media/search?query=Norway%20Chess)

**Lichess**: also provides the live broadcast of moves via its dedicated
study page for each round of the tournament. The advantage is more
freedom to customize the engine analysis while following a game and also more suitable for following the moves live from your phone.

- [Dedicated study page for current round](https://lichess.org/broadcast/norway-chess-2019-round-3/qo1ItVY1)

**Miscellaneous**: There are also various streams providing commentary for the event (see e.g. the twitch page of chess streams), among them is the chessbrah channel having Yasser Seirawan and Nils Grandelius currently as guests.

- [Twitch page of live chess streams](https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Chess)
- [Chessbrah channel](https://www.twitch.tv/chessbrah), with invited guests providing live commentary.

So there's plenty to choose from given what you're most interested in.
If there's one thing I would definitely recommend, is to watch Peter
Svidler's post analysis videos of the game of the round
as they are highly instructive and fun.

- [All of his uploaded sessions on chess24's YT](https://www.youtube.com/user/chess24media/search?query=peter%20svidler)
- [Restricted to the Norway Chess event](https://www.youtube.com/user/chess24media/search?query=Norway%20chess%20peter%20svidler)

Comment: Nicely detailed answer! To add a bit of info, i've seen Nakamura also streaming the event on Twitch. Not sure if it is in his own channel or in chess.com's one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are looking for (comments, video...) but if you are just are looking for the games, chessbomb has them live: https://www.chessbomb.com/arena/2019-altibox-norway-chess